# Can F1 Student Resident Alien Buy From Treasury Direct?

Tags: united-states, bonds, treasury, f1-student-visa

I've been in the United States for 10 Years now on F1 VISA. I've filed taxes and got a SSN 5 years ago. I have a drivers license and an EAD. I'm a resident alien for tax purposes.

Can I open an account and buy from TreasureDirect? Is it legal?
If not, can I buy Bills/Bonds from third parties like Fidelity?

Answer (score 1):

You can open a TD account. See [the FAQ](https://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/help/treasurydirect-help/faq/#id-opening-an-account-865183):

> In order to open a TreasuryDirect account, an individual or entity account manager must have a valid Social Security Number (SSN), be 18 years of age or over, and be legally competent

You'll need a US address and bank account (same source):

> The account owner must also have a United States address of record and have an account at a U.S. depository financial institution that will accept debits and credits using the Automated Clearing House method of payment

If you have a brokerage account, you can definitely buy treasuries there as well, although not all types of bonds available on TD could be resold on a secondary market.